# BigQuery not applying outside where condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, openstreetmap

Looking at OpenStreetMap database and Big Query, this query returns 1000 rows

```
SELECT * FROM 

(

  SELECT 
  feature_type, 
  osm_id, 
  osm_way_id, 
  osm_version, 
  osm_timestamp,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key = 'highway') roadtype,
  geometry

  FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_features` osm

  WHERE 'highway' IN (SELECT key FROM UNNEST(all_tags)) LIMIT 1000
)
WHERE roadtype = 'service' or roadtype = 'residential' or roadtype = 'primary'
AND osm_id = 682085476
AND NOT ST_ISRING(geometry)
```

and each row has different osm_id, while this query returns only 1, as expected

```
SELECT * FROM 

(

  SELECT 
  feature_type, 
  osm_id, 
  osm_way_id, 
  osm_version, 
  osm_timestamp,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(all_tags) WHERE key = 'highway') roadtype,
  geometry

  FROM `bigquery-public-data.geo_openstreetmap.planet_features` osm

  WHERE 'highway' IN (SELECT key FROM UNNEST(all_tags)) and osm_id = 682085476 LIMIT 1000
)
WHERE roadtype = 'service' or roadtype = 'residential' or roadtype = 'primary'
```

Question:
Why the `where` condition in the first query not applied to the inner query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the `where` condition in the first query is applied to the inner query, but the problem is that the `AND` operator has precedence over `OR` operator. The `AND` operator would execute first then the `OR` operator, so, the where condition in your first query would be executed as the following:

```
WHERE roadtype = 'service' or roadtype = 'residential' or 
(roadtype = 'primary' AND osm_id = 682085476 AND NOT ST_ISRING(geometry))
```

But you are looking for:

```
WHERE (roadtype = 'service' or roadtype = 'residential' or roadtype = 'primary')
AND osm_id = 682085476
AND NOT ST_ISRING(geometry)
```

That means we have to use parentheses to override the default evaluation.